# Subscreen in tab not getting refreshed

Tags: abap

I have a selection screen on which I want to change tabs dynamically. In my example `tab1` should be shown if the flag `p_flg1` is set otherwise `tab2` is to be presented and the other one deactivated.

```
REPORT zzz.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b2 WITH FRAME TITLE tit1.
  PARAMETERS:
    p_flg1 TYPE abap_bool AS CHECKBOX USER-COMMAND md DEFAULT abap_true. "Master data
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b2.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF TABBED BLOCK tab FOR 20 lines.
  SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (54) tab1 USER-COMMAND tab1 DEFAULT SCREEN 010.
  SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (54) tab2 USER-COMMAND tab2 DEFAULT SCREEN 011.
  SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (54) tab3 USER-COMMAND tab3 DEFAULT SCREEN 900.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK tab.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 010 AS SUBSCREEN.
  PARAMETERS:
    p_flg2 TYPE abap_bool AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 010.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 011 AS SUBSCREEN.
  PARAMETERS:
    p_text TYPE text.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 011.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 900 AS SUBSCREEN.
  PARAMETERS:
    p_flg3 TYPE abap_bool AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 900.

INITIALIZATION.
tit1 = 'Tit1'.
tab1 = 'Tab1'.
tab2 = 'Tab2'.
tab3 = 'Tab3'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-name = 'TAB1'.
      IF p_flg1 = abap_true.
        screen-active = 1.
      ELSE.
        screen-active = 0.
      ENDIF.
    ELSEIF screen-name = 'TAB2'.
      IF p_flg1 = abap_true.
        screen-active = 0.
      ELSE.
        screen-active = 1.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
    MODIFY SCREEN.
  ENDLOOP.
```

However what gets changed after unsetting the parameter `p_flg1` is only the tab name and not the subscreen under it. It only gets changed if I switch to the `tab3` and back.

After starting the program.

[image: After program start]

After unsetting the `P_FLG1` only the tab name gets changed not the subscreen under it.

[image: After unsetting P_FLG1]

To work around it I have to switch to Tab3...

[image: Switch to tab 3]

...and back

[image: After getting back to tab 2]

I assume that I need to call something, e.g. a function module after `MODIFY SCREEN` to execute some event (maybe PAI?) however I failed in finding any information on that.

What do I have to do to get the subscreen under the tab refreshed immediately after setting/unsetting the flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue - if you disable/hide the first tab of a register, the subscreen of the first card stays in place until the user selects a different card. A register is essentially a subscreen area with a button bar on top, and if the included screen isn't changed by something, the default is displayed. You might get a better result using the "Dynamic Assignment" described [here](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/ABAPSELECTION-SCREEN_TABBED.htm) (approx. center of the page). If this doesn't work, you might have to emulate the card change after the checkbox has been changed. Of course, the simple solution would be to move the third (static) card to the front...

Comment: Genius of a man! Adding `tab-dynnr = '0010'` and `tab-dynnr = '0011'` after `screen-active = 1` as described in "Dynamic Assignment" did the job without the need to reorganize the register. Thanks!